# PyAutoGUI unable to import pyscreeze due to Pillow compatibility issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pyautogui, pyscreeze

PyAutoGUI unable to import pyscreeze due to Pillow compatibility issue.
I attempted updating pyscreeze and pyautogui, both did nothing.

Error:

```
_couldNotImportPyScreeze
raise PyAutoGUIException(
pyautogui.PyAutoGUIException: PyAutoGUI was unable to import pyscreeze. (This is likely because you're running a version of Python that Pillow (which pyscreeze depends on) doesn't support currently.) Please install this module to enable the function you tried to call.
```

I attempted updating pyscreeze and pyautogui, both did nothing.

Comment: Better update all libraries.